# C - Add odd digits of a number to the end of another number

Tags: c, numbers

I'm trying to write a function that adds the odd digits of one number to the end of a second number, without using arrays. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int NumberAdd (int n, int m)
{
int power=1,x=0,counter=0,newnumber;
while(n!=0)
    {
    if(n%2!=0)
    {
        x=x+(n%10)*power;
        power*=10;
        counter++;
    }
    n=n/10;
    }

        newnumber=m*pow(10,counter)+x;
        return newnumber;

        }
int main ()
{
int m,n;
scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

printf("%d\n", NumberAdd(n,m));

return 0;
}
```

Now, from my experience, this should work, and it does work if the first number is an odd number, but if the number I'm trying to get the odd digits from is an even number I get problems. For example:

For 3457 and 3458 I get 3458357 as a result. But, for 3456 and 3457 I get 345734. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to avoid floating point arithmetic due to possible rounding issues. Try something like this (could be made shorter, but I tried to keep the original structure):

```
int NumberAdd(int n, int m)
{
    int power = 1, x = 0, newnumber;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        if (n % 2 != 0)
        {
            x = x + (n % 10)*power;
            power *= 10;
        }
        n = n / 10;
    }

    newnumber = m * power + x;
    return newnumber;
}
```

Comment: @AndrejNaumovski I updated the code a bit. You can just use the `power` you calculated already, instead of calling `pow()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAXNUM 1000000000

int NumberAdd (int n, int m)
{
    int quotient, divisor = MAXNUM;
    do {
        quotient = n / divisor;
        if (quotient & 1)
            m = m * 10 + quotient;
        n = n - quotient * divisor;
        divisor /= 10;
    }
    while (divisor);
    return m;
}
```